# Convert mongodb query with regex in $in condition To lumenEloquent

Tags: php, mongodb, eloquent, mongodb-query, lumen

**How to convert mongodb query to lumen eloquent for below mongodb query ?**

**Mongodb query:**

`db.employees.find({"phone":{$in:[/456$/,/389$/]}});`

*I tried with lumen eloquent(see below) for above mongodb query, but not expected result...*

**Lumen eloquent :-**

`Employees::whereIn("phone",["/456$/","/389$/"])->get();`

Answer (score 0):

```
Employees::whereIn("phone"=>["456$","389$"])->get();
```

Comment: Thank you!,...
*I tried as below.... But not giving expected result*

**Employees::whereIn("phone",["456$","389$"])->get();**

Comment: Hey @GQ. did you manage to find a working solution? "456$" is not working for me neither.

Comment: Hi @IvanToncev use add your desired values instead of ["456$","389$"] array :)
it was an example

Comment: Yep, I figured that out :)
But it's not working for me with my values. Is $ at the end how you show whereIn that it's regex actually?

Comment: Because in my case it just filters by literal "my_string$", it's not working like regex. So maybe I am doing something. wrong.